# PHP AWS S3 - unable to upload file in s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an audio .mp3 file to s3 bucket.I have followed [this](http://medium.com/@martindrapeau/simple-php-code-to-push-files-to-aws-s3-3396f9b3d02a) tutorial. I have defined credentials, bucket. When I execute the code, it gets executed successfully. However, when I check s3 bucket, no file is uploaded.

Below is the snapshot of the prints before and afte the upload, and the file name I have printed.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
$tmpfile = $_FILES["speaker1"]["tmp_name"];
$file = $_FILES['speaker1']['name'];
require_once('S3.php');
S3::setAuth(AWS_S3_KEY, AWS_S3_SECRET);
S3::setRegion(AWS_S3_REGION);
S3::setSignatureVersion('v4');
S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($tmpfile), AWS_S3_BUCKET, $file, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="sendtoserver_v2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return test();">
    <div class="info">
        <input type="hidden" name="speakers" id="speakers">
        <input class="fname" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" id="title">

        <select id="selecting" name="selecting" onchange="addMajorList();">
            <option value="number" disabled selected>Number of Files</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="assetdiv">
        <label>Asset</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="asset" name="asset">
    </div>
    <div id="speaker1div">
        <br/>
        <label>Speaker 1</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="speaker1" name="speaker1" onchange="counting();">
    </div>
    <div id="speaker2div">
        <br/>
        <label>Speaker 2</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="speaker2" name="speaker2" onchange="counting();">
    </div>
    <div id="speaker3div">
        <br/>
        <label>Speaker 3</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="speaker3" name="speaker3" onchange="counting();">
    </div>
    <div id="speaker4div">
        <br/>
        <label>Speaker 4</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="speaker4" name="speaker4" onchange="counting();">
    </div>
    <div id="speaker5div">
        <br/>
        <label>Speaker 5</label>
        <br/>
        <input class="form-control info" type="file" id="speaker5" name="speaker5" onchange="counting();">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I followed the code on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html and it seems to work fine, not sure about the code you have.

Comment: print the error ?

Comment: Its odd to see `$_FILES["speaker1"]` and `$_FILES['file']` please show your form

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps I did enclosed the code in try catch block but no error.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have edited the question, please have a look

Comment: @NigelRen I tried that code, but same behaviour, not getting any error

Comment: I dont see `name="file"` in your html, also change it to use an array, then you only need loop over the array serverside instead of checking all and breaking DRY

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I changed $_FILES['file'] to $_FILES['speaker1'], now it is showing the file name, but still does not give any error

Comment: I have put some print commands before and after the 'putObject' function. added the snapshot